# How to reset a class attribute value to 0?

Tags: python, oop, blackjack

I am coding a blackjack game using OOP in Python.

One of my class attributes for both the dealer and player class is:

```
class Dealer:
    def __init__(self, name, balance):
        self.name = name
        self.balance = balance
        self.hand = []
        self.value = 0

class Player:
    def __init__(self, name, balance):
        self.name = name
        self.balance = balance
        self.hand = []
        self.value = 0
```

After each round, I want to reset my self.value back to 0 for both dealer and player.

I tried using a setter method:

```
def setValue(self):
    return self.value == 0
```

But it is obviously giving me a boolean value instead of setting the value back to 0.

Can anybody provide feedback on how best I should go about this?

Comment: How did you set it to zero the first time? And what does your setter do? Can you see any difference in those two lines?

Comment: That is an incorrect setter method. You are not setting anything. You are just returning a bool response.

Comment: Just use `variable.value = 0`, where `variable` holds one of the objects.

Comment: Wouldn't `self.value = 0` work in the set method?

Answer (score 1):

`self.value == 0` is a condition. Its value will either `True` or `False`. and when you use `return`, you return that value where function is originally called.

Essentially, whenever you call `setValue`, you are checking if the value is 0 or not.

this is what you need to do

```
def setValue(self):
    self.value = 0
```

setter method doesn't need to return anything, it just sets the value of the attribute.

Answer (score 0):

`==` means that you compare two values and check if they're the same. What you want to do is use `=` when assigning values. This is the answer:

```
def setValue(self):
    self.value = 0
```

Comment: Assignment isn't an expression, you can't use it in a `return` statement.

Comment: @Barmar right, I forgot to remove the `return` when copying his code.

Comment: @Barmar: Technically you can with `return (x := 0)` but it doesn't work with attributes.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to add a reset method to each of the classes:

```
class Dealer:
    def __init__(self, name, balance):
        self.name = name
        self.balance = balance
        self.hand = []
        self.value = 0

    def reset(self):
        self.value = 0

class Player:
    def __init__(self, name, balance):
        self.name = name
        self.balance = balance
        self.hand = []
        self.value = 0

    def reset(self):
        self.value = 0
```

So if you have a `d` object representing dealer and `p1`, `p2` and `p3` representing players then at the start of the round you can call.

```
d.reset()
p1.reset()
p2.reset()
p3.reset()
```

This will work but it's not very clean.

Similarly, you can define `reset()` method in the base class since Player and Dealer are very similar. Just would like to point out that it doesn't make a whole lot of sense for `Dealer` to have a balance.

Alternative way is to create an external function and use duck typing so it can accept any object that defines a `reset()` method:

```
from typing import Protocol

class Resettable(Protocol):    
    def reset(self):
        pass  

def reset_multiple(objects: list[Resettable]):
    for i in objects:
        i.reset()

d = Dealer('John', 100)
p1 = Player('Jane', 120)
p2 = Player('Jim', 150)

reset_multiple([d, p1, p2])

print(d.value, p1.value, p2.value)   # Out: 0, 0, 0
```

Here the `reset_multiple()` accepts a list of any object that follows a Protocol of having a `reset()` method and then simply calls it.